# Save the FourSquare Details locally in Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, foursquare

In my app, I integrated the Foursquare API to fetch the near by places.

I got the relevant code from [Github](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/Foursquare-API-v2)

I send the request every time to fetch the near by places. But how can I save the places locally & display it without requesting all time if user has already visited the same place before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some sort of persistent datastore (either server-side or client-side) to save search results from Foursquare. You can save user check-in data (i.e., whether or not a user has visited a place) as well, but be aware that according to our [policies](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/community), you can't save this data for more than 24 hours. If you want an up-to-date snapshot of whether or not a person has visited certain places, you're better off doing these queries on-the-fly instead of saving.